# short or shortly or in short

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I'd like to know how to use *short/shortly* properly in the following:

> It is a long story, but I'll try to put it as **short** as possible.
>   It is a long story, but I'll try to put it as **shortly** as possible.

I also wonder if *in short* would be correct:

> It is a long story, but I'll try to put it **in short**.

Comment: [Don't use 'shortly' to say that something lasts or is done for a short time. Don't say, for example, 'She told them shortly what had happened'. Use briefly.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shortly)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't "put it" short, you'd "keep it short".  Alternatively, you'd "keep it brief", an option that sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

"Short" is an adjective, while "Shortly" is an adverb. Grammatically speaking, the proper thing to do is to use "short" to describe nouns/things, and "shortly" to describe verbs/actions. 
In the first situation, **It is a long story, but I'll try to put it as short as possible.**, you are describing the **noun**, namely, you're saying that you'll make the story short.
In the second situation, **It is a long story, but I'll try to put it as shortly as possible.**, you are describing the **action**, namely, you're talking about how long it will take you to talk about the story. 
In the final situation, **"It is a long story, but I'll try to put it in short."**, you are again describing the **noun**, namely, how the story will be put by you. 
All of these three ways are grammatically acceptable, and their meanings are often conflated in everyday conversation.

Comment: You've got several problems here.  You say use *shortly* to modify verbs, and then your example is "put it **as short**", which is an adverbial use, one of manner.  Perhaps *make it short*.  Your last example uses "put it in short", which strikes me unidiomatic, with unfortunate resonances with *put in* as a phrasal verb or *in short* as a prepositional phrase.  And you don't mention the real reason not to use *shortly* to indicate length -- the word's conflicting meanings: after a brief pause, and curtly.  By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but how is "put it as short as possible" an adverbial use? "Short" is modifying "it", (similar to talking about putting ice cream on an ice cream cone ("make it as tall as possible") or or talking about an essay's length ("make it as short as possible")), so why would it be an adverb in this sense, as opposed to an adjective?

Comment: So it means "put the short it"?  I don't think so.  *As short as possible* says how to do the putting, i.e., in as short a manner as possible.  And that's an adverbial usage, one of (no surprise) manner.  *Make it short* has *short* as an objective complement, a usage which requires a categorizing verb: *elected him President*, *labeled it offensive*, and the like.  I don't think such a usage is idiomatic with *put*.

Comment: It wouldn't be "put the short it", it'd be "put short it", which makes perfect grammatical sense (although it does sound awkward to say aloud). And I disagree; I think "elected him President" and "put it short" are analogous grammatically.

Comment: *Put short it* doesn't make sense either, let alone "perfect" sense.  And regardless of what you think, *put* doesn't license a second object as a complement.  As I said, that requires a verb of categorization or labeling.  I could be convinced by evidence.  Got any?  The google reports many uses of "put it short", and I've only looked at the first few pages -- non-English speakers, false drops, and adverbs of manner.  Maybe you can do better.

Comment: Hm. I suppose that would lead to some awkward/potentially incorrect constructions ("kill it dead"). However, I've always assumed it could work for pretty much any word, and the succeeding adjective would just mean the state to leave the object of the verb in on conclusion of the verb (i.e., "Fly the plane high", "Retrieve the person alive"). After talking to a linguistics major friend of mine, though, they brought up an interesting point that I hope we can establish: are there any rules that say that isn't the case? Because usage-wise, it seems that's how the trend goes.

Comment: I think *kill it dead* is fine:  essentially, mark it in the category of the not living.  The sentence doesn't tell you how to kill it like say, *kill it with poison*.  But *fly the plane high* is different from *kill it dead*.  That tells you either how to fly the plane or where to fly it.  In *retrieve the person alive*, you're not saving a live person.  That would hardly need saying.  If you didn't mean a live person, you'd say, "Retrieve the corpse."  Consider *retrieve the person dead or alive*.  Is "dead or alive" really the ultimate state of the object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36783/discussion-between-deadrat-and-david-mcknight).