# "Shortly" vs "in short"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Here is a Danish sentence that I'd like to translate to English:

> Programmet vil kort, præcist og motiverende guide dig fra A til B.

A first attempt of translating it would be:

> The program will shortly, precisely and motivationally lead you from A to B.

I am aware that the word `shortly` refers to time rather than length/size when used in this manner. So I'll rewrite that adverb to `in short` in this way:

> The program will precisely, motivationally and in short lead you from A to B.

In this answer: [short or shortly or in short](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84264/short-or-shortly-or-in-short) the suggested solutions seem to be a bit different, though, and not perfectly matching my sentence here. (For instance, how would I use the word `brief`)?

**My first question is: Is this a correct use of `in short`, as in the writing being kept short in size?**

Secondly, the word `motivationally` seems off for me. I would rather write a word like `motivatingly`, but that word does not seem to exist in English.

**My second question is therefore: Is the word `motivationally` used correctly here or should I replace it with another word/phrasing?**

Comment: _In short_ usually means that you are about to add a brief summary of something you have already been speaking about. _Shortly_ usually means _soon_, so in this context it would be better to use _briefly_.

Comment: I'd use *quickly*.

Comment: @Justin Does "quickly" not solely refer to time?

Comment: @Steeven - I think I misunderstood that you actually meant small amounts of text. I'll retract *quickly* and say *concisely and efficiently* instead.

Answer (score 2):

*In short* is usually a meta-linguistic phrase, commenting about the sentence it is inserted in. So in your example *in short* would be saying "we are abbreviating what we are saying about what the programme will do". I don't think this is what you intend.

I think "briefly" will do what you want. "Concisely" is another possibility, but you probably don't want that just before "precisely".

I agree with you about "motivationally". *Motivatingly* is perfectly understandable, but seems awkward. There is no obvious alternative that occurs to me, unless you move the idea into the verb, with something like:

> will briefly and precisely motivate you to go from A to B.

I'd need more context to know whether that works or not.